# Correlation analysis on .json inputs

Tags: python, json, api

I Need help codeing a correlation analysis on json data from user input in python.

I am needing to take inputs from a front end UI in the format shown below (examples is of one day, but inputs would be day over day. If more days would help, let me know):

```
{
  "username": "8gscMQSejG77F2PC8",
  "pastObservations": [
    {
      "performances": {
        "Mood": 8,
        "Energy": 9,
        "Productivity": 8
      },
      "observations": {
        "Running": 10,
        "Sleep (Quality)": 5,
        "Sleep (Amount)": 6,
        "Meditation (Quality)": 5,
        "Meditation (Time)": 10,
        "Calories": 6,
        "Duration": 8,
        "Water": 4
      },
      "day": "2019-1-29"
    },
  ],
  "currentObservations": {
    "performances": {
      "Mood": 8,
      "Energy": 9,
      "Productivity": 8
    },
    "observations": {
      "Running": 10,
      "Sleep (Quality)": 5,
      "Sleep (Amount)": 6,
      "Meditation (Quality)": 5,
      "Meditation (Time)": 10,
      "Calories": 6,
      "Duration": 8,
      "Water": 4
    },
    "day": "2019-1-29"
  }
}
```

This type of daily user input needs to be collected in a db and have a correlation analysis ran on it to identify dependancies/correlation between the 'observations' and the 'performances'.

Comment: Do you need help with the db or just the correlation?

Comment: What you actually have is an Extract-Transform-Load problem and an analysis problem.  The `pandas` module in python can read JSON that is formatted a certain way and turn it into a dataframe.  There is also a `json` module in python that is lower level and will turn your data into a dict or array with various properties.

Comment: Tim, I am new at all of this (coding. About 2 months in). I figured out how to set up a basic sqlite3 database, but not how to have the app send the information provided into that database. I think I can figure out the analysis piece, but not how to call the information from the analysis output. Any guidance or suggests regarding where to learn would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Paul, thanks. That is great info. I'll dive into ETL (just looked it up) and hopefully will be able to come back with more specific issues that I am sure I'll run into. 

As I said to Tim, any resources you know of where I can dive into such things and learn, let me know. The resources I have found all seem to be beginner level. 

Thanks.